# How to include the output of a shell command in org-mode source code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

For example, I got a demo to show a command and its output, and I want to insert them into an `.org` file like a source code snippet of C or something. I then want to be able to export the file to an HTML file, and have the block highlighted just like examples are in many books.

For example, I have

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
$ ls
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
...
or any other examples like this
...
#+END_SRC
```

but it cannot be converted to HTML: An error message that reads

> `shell-mode`: Wrong type argument: processp, nil

shows up all the time. What mode should I use to replace `shell`, and if I should not use the `#+BEGIN_SRC...#+END_SRC` format, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to construct examples yourself (that's what I'm getting from your question, but correct me if I'm wrong), use an `EXAMPLE` block instead of a `SRC` block:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
$ ls
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
...
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

When exporting to HTML, this block becomes:

```html
<pre class="example">
$ ls
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
...
</pre>
```

As you can see, the contents of the exported block are exactly the same as the contents of the original `EXAMPLE` block.

---

If you actually want to *run* one or more commands to produce output dynamically and include both the commands and the results in your HTML document, you need to modify the `SRC` block to look like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports both
ls
#+END_SRC
```

If the output of the `ls` command includes the directories and files you listed in your example (`dir1`, `dir2`, `file1`, `file2`), this will export to:

```html
<div class="org-src-container">
  <pre class="src src-sh">
    ls
  </pre>
</div>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="left" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">dir1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">dir2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">file1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">file2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the code itself is wrapped in a code block, and the results are listed in a table.

**Note** that you will need to enable support for `sh` code blocks explicitly via:

```el
(require 'ob-sh)
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((sh . t)))
```

This is because by default [Org Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) only enables support for Emacs Lisp code blocks (as explained [here](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var%2Forg-babel-load-languages.html)).

Comment: Thank you for the `ob` thing, I got two more problems, `1`: is there any `built-in shortcut` to insert the pair of BEGIN_EXAMPLE, like `<s then TAB` to insert the `BEGIN_EXAMPLE` besides to define a snippet in `yasnippet`? `2`: I got `org-html-handle-links: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error message after changing the `BEGIN_EXAMPLE` but nothing more, there must be something wrong about the link in my org file, there are a lot of them, how I can make `org-export` to show more detail such as line number that is wrong when exporting failed??

Comment: Addressing your first question: Yes, there is, it's `<e` followed by `TAB`. See [Easy Templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html) for a full list.

Comment: As for your second question: I'm not sure I know what you mean. What link(s)? There aren't any links in your original example. As a general piece of advice, try to get a minimal example working first. Put the `EXAMPLE` block as shown in my answer into a new file by itself. Don't add anything else. Then try to export it and see what happens. If that works, gradually add more stuff and keep exporting as you do. If you run into an error at some point you will know that the last addition (or change) you made is causing it.

Comment: The problem of my original post is solved by BEGIN_EXAMPLE. BEGIN_EXAMPLE error is located by the `org-export` itself, so I know it is the BEGIN_SRC issue, but there are a lot more in my original file, after `org-export`, only the `org-html-handle-links: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error message shows up and I don't where the exact position is.

Comment: @CodyChan I'm not following. If you want me to have a look at the contents of the file you are trying to export, add it to your question (you can remove it again later).

Comment: @CodyChan Alternatively, if my answer solved your problem and the issue you are having now is unrelated to the original issue, you might want to consider accepting my answer and posting a separate question.

Comment: It turns out that if you create a link to a local file, the description of the link cannot contains the extension of the file, such as `[[~/Pictures/image.png][Image.png]]` will definitely cause the `org-html-handle-links: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error, weird...

Comment: @CodyChan I see, thanks for clearing that up. So your problem is solved now, yes? :)